# Can I loop create Triggers for all tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have such script which in theory allows me to create the same Trigger for each table in DB:

```
DECLARE @insertTriggers VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @insertTriggers = @insertTriggers1 + *Some Trigger creation code ending with 'GO'"
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
EXEC(@insertTriggers);
```

When I use PRINT and copy it to different query it works because I can seperate CREATE TRIGGERS with keyword GO. Here it doesn't work. What can I do? Do I have to make a seperate code for each Trigger?

Comment: `GO` is an SSMS/sqlcmd keyword (it's a batch separator); it isn't a T-SQL Keyword. You can't put a `GO` statement in a dynamic statement. If you need to do several batches, you need to make multiple calls to `sp_executesql`.

Comment: So I pass each table as argument? via this sp_exectuesql?

Comment: Might be better if we understand what you're actually trying to achieve here. You can't pass an object's name as a parameter to `sp_executesql` though, no.

Comment: It is 'AFTER INSERT' trigger and it checks if the inserted values aren't the same as a row in another table excluding some columns. Basicaly checks if it's duplicate, if not it Inserts those values to this another table. And it is done to a set of tables in the database.

Comment: Use an `;` seperator between queries instead of GO ?

Comment: I guess I can make a variable next to `WHERE TABLE_NAME = @variable` is this correct thinking?

Comment: If you're doing this to the whole database, stop and ask yourself if you're using the right tool for the job. Without knowing what these triggers do, it's difficult to offer a concrete suggestion but there are *lots* of tools built into SQL Server that deal with changing data at various levels of resolution and hand-rolling your own triggers is about the worst way to go usually.

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER` must be the first statement in the batch @Martin. `CREATE TRIGGER... BEGIN {whole trigger statement} END; CREATE TRIGGER...` would fail.

Comment: @Martin I did that and got error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'`

Comment: @Passer7by: In that case it cannot be done. Just execute each CREATE TRIGGER seperately.

Comment: Notepad ++  comes in handy for this..just print the code copy in it and by using macro replace GO Whit GO + Enter..then just execute the code..

Comment: Can't I use `sp_executesql` multiple times and pass string of table's name for each?

Comment: @Passer7by, I had a similar problem historically, which I managed to solve by creating a `Stored Procedure` that dynamically creates the triggers for each table even if the column names do not match... Advise whether this would work for you?

Comment: I've never used `Stored Procedure` before, need to read about it first. Do you have some example available to view?

Comment: I will post my Stored Procedure - I developed this SP for Audit Purposes and it might not specifically work for you, but if you understand the code, you can alter it to your advantage - will be posting it as your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as template to create your triggers..

```
DECLARE @TriggerTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TriggerNameTemplate NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @Tables TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, TableName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Tables 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

DECLARE @ID INT, @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @TriggerName NVARCHAR(250)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Tables)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ID, @TableName = TableName FROM @Tables
    SET @TriggerName = REPLACE(@TriggerNameTemplate,'#TableName#', QUOTENAME(@TableName))
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE name = @TriggerName)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'DROP TRIGGER ' + @TriggerName
        EXEC (@SQL)
    END
    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@TriggerTemplate,'#TableName#', QUOTENAME(@TableName))

    EXEC(@SQL)

    DELETE @Tables WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I developed this SP for audit purposes and it might not work for you originally, but if you alter it, I'm sure it'll assist you.

Otherwise, alter your question of what you need the triggers to do and I will then alter my answer to work for you...

```
if exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'kv_sp_dbAudits_tr_AW')
drop procedure kv_sp_dbAudits_tr_AW
go

set ansi_nulls on
go

set quoted_identifier on
go

create procedure kv_sp_dbAudits_tr_AW(@tablename varchar(150),@switch bit)
as

BEGIN

if exists(select name from sysobjects where name = 'TempTableTriggers')
drop table TempTableTriggers;

create table TempTableTriggers (tablename varchar(100),columns varchar(max),columnvars varchar(max),columnvarst varchar(max),columnalloc varchar(max))

declare @query          varchar(max)
,       @loop           int
,       @dbname         varchar(50) =   (select db_name())+'_Audit'
,       @table          varchar(100)
,       @tableau        varchar(100)
,       @trigger        varchar(100)
,       @column         varchar(max)
,       @columnvars     varchar(max)
,       @columnvarst    varchar(max)
,       @columnalloc    varchar(max)
,       @crlf           char(2)         =   char(13)+char(10)

        declare @Tables table
        (   id  int identity primary key
        ,   TableName   varchar(100)
        ,   TriggerName varchar(100)
        ,   Columns     varchar(max))

    if @tablename like ''+'%'+''
        set @tablename  =   @tablename
    else
        set @tablename  =   ''+@tablename+''

    set @trigger = @tablename+'_Audit_kvtr_AW'

    begin
        if  @switch = 1
            begin
                if exists(select name from sysobjects where name = @trigger)
                    begin
                        set @tablename  =   (select name from sysobjects where name = @tablename)
                        set @query      =   @crlf
                        set @query      =   @query + @crlf
                        set @query      =   @query + @crlf
                        set @query      =   @query + @crlf
                        set @query      =   @query + replicate('-',80)+@crlf
                        set @query      =   @query + @crlf
                        set @query      =   @query + 'The audit trigger "'+@tablename+'_Audit_kvtr_AW'+'" already exists!'
                        print (@query)
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        if @tablename = 'all'

                            insert into @Tables
                            (   TableName   )
                            select
                            name
                            from    sysobjects
                            where   xtype   =   'u'
                            and name not like   '%audit%'
                            and name <>         'TempTableTriggers'
                            order by name

                        else

                            insert into @Tables
                            (   TableName   )
                            select
                            name
                            from    sysobjects
                            where   xtype   =   'u'
                            and name not like   '%audit%'
                            and name <>         'TempTableTriggers'
                            and name = @tablename
                            order by name

                        select @loop = min(id) from @Tables
                        while @loop is not null

                        begin
                                begin
                                    set @query  =   '   declare @columns        varchar(max)

                                                    select @columns = stuff((select '','' + char(10)+quotename(Column_Name)
                                                    from information_schema.columns
                                                    where   table_name = '''+(select TableName from @Tables where id = @loop)+'''
                                                    and Column_Name <> ''cAllocs''
                                                    and data_type not in (''text'',''image'',''ntext'')
                                                    group by column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, ordinal_position
                                                    order by ordinal_position
                                                    for xml path(''''), type).value(''.'', ''nvarchar(max)''),1,1,'''')

                                                    insert into TempTableTriggers   (tablename,columns)
                                                    select  distinct
                                                        table_name
                                                    ,   @columns
                                                    from information_schema.columns
                                                    where   table_name = '''+(select TableName from @Tables where id = @loop)+''''
                                    exec (@query)
                                end
                            select @loop = min(id) from @Tables where id>@loop
                        end

                        insert into @Tables
                        (TriggerName,TableName,Columns)
                        select
                        TableName,TableName,columns
                        from    TempTableTriggers

                        select @loop = min(id) from @Tables
                        while @loop is not null

                        begin
                                begin
                                    select  @trigger        =   TriggerName+'_Audit_kvtr_AW'
                                    ,       @tableau        =   TableName+'_Audit'
                                    ,       @table          =   TableName
                                    ,       @column         =   Columns
                                    from                        @Tables
                                    where   id              =   @loop

                                        set @query  =           'create trigger '+@trigger+' on '+@table+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'with encryption'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'after insert, update, delete'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'as'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ '/***********************************************************************************************************************************'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'Description        :   To insert any change made in '+@table+' into '+@dbname+'.dbo.'+@table+'_Audit'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'Author         :   Attie Wagner'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'Creation Date  :   30  October 2018'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'Modified By        :   Attie Wagner'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'Modified Date  :   28  January 2019'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ '************************************************************************************************************************************/'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'begin'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'set nocount on'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf

                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'if (select trigger_nestlevel(object_id('''+@trigger+'''))) > 1'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'return'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf

                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'declare @inserted varchar(15) = '''''+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'declare @deleted varchar(15) = '''''+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'declare @updated varchar(15) = '''''+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'declare @action varchar(15) = '''''+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'if((exists(select * from inserted)) and (exists(select * from deleted)))'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ '   set @updated = ''updated'''+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'else'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'if(exists(select * from inserted))'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ '   set @inserted = ''new'''+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'else'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'if(exists(select * from deleted))'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ '   set @deleted = ''deleted'''+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'set @action = (select case when @inserted = ''new'' then ''new'' when @updated = ''updated'' then ''updated'' when @deleted = ''deleted'' then ''deleted'' else '''' end)'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf

                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'declare @kvAgent varchar(100)  =   (select cAgentName from _rtblAgents where idAgents  =   [dbo]._efnAgentIDFromConnection(''dbo''))'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf

                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'if @action in (''new'',''updated'')'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf

                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'begin'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+     'insert into ['+@dbname+'].dbo.'+@tableau+' ('+@column+','+@crlf+'kvUsername,'+@crlf+'kvDTStamp,'+@crlf+'kvAction)'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+     'select '+@column+','+@crlf+'@kvAgent,'+@crlf+'getdate(),'+@crlf+'@action'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+     'from inserted'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'end;'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf

                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'if @action = ''deleted'''+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf

                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'begin'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+     'insert into ['+@dbname+'].dbo.'+@tableau+' ('+@column+','+@crlf+'kvUsername,'+@crlf+'kvDTStamp,'+@crlf+'kvAction)'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+     'select '+@column+','+@crlf+'@kvAgent,'+@crlf+'getdate(),'+@crlf+'@action'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+     'from deleted'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'end;'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf

                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'begin'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+     'delete '+quotename(@dbname)+'.dbo.'+@table+'_Audit'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+     'where  datediff(month,kvDTStamp,getdate()) > 12'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'end;'+@crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ @crlf
                                        set @query  =   @query+ 'end;'+@crlf

                                    exec (@query)
                                end
                            select @loop = min(id) from @Tables where id>@loop
                        end
                    end

                drop table TempTableTriggers;
            end
        else
            begin
                if @tablename = 'all'

                    insert into @Tables
                    (   TriggerName )
                    select name from sysobjects
                    where xtype = 'tr'
                    and name like   '%_Audit_kvtr_AW'
                    order by name

                else

                    insert into @Tables
                    (   TriggerName )
                    select name from sysobjects
                    where xtype = 'tr'
                    and name like   '%_Audit_kvtr_AW'
                    and name = @tablename+'_Audit_kvtr_AW'
                    order by name

                select @loop = min(id) from @Tables
                while @loop is not null

                begin
                        begin
                            set @trigger    =   (select TriggerName from @Tables where id = @loop)
                            set @query      =   'if exists(select name from sysobjects where name = '''+@trigger+''')'+@crlf
                            set @query      =   @query+'drop trigger '+@trigger
                            exec (@query)
                        end
                    select @loop = min(id) from @Tables where id>@loop
                end
            end
    end
END;
```